# Client/Server in Separate Projects or in One

Tags: java, python, eclipse, project-management, directory

I've written a small Client-/Server software (chat program).

It is composed of a server script (pyhon), a desktop-client (python), a webinterface and an android-client (java).

> How would you organize this? (folder-structure, ...)

I would love to have one big project, but if I only push them all together in a src folder, everything looks very messy. (With the differences of the java and python package naming conventions)

> Does eclipse offer a functionality to display such multi-language projects?

Answer (score 2):

It is good to keep each component in a dedicated space, and if there is something in common that is shared between them, I would turn it into an independent project too. I also would not mix the java source tree with the python one, to avoid mixing everything up.

Something like

```
/projectname/python/src/core/
/projectname/python/src/server/
/projectname/python/src/client/
```

I would do the same to the android source tree.

Hope this helps.

Cheers